# writing a code for time to double annual interest rate

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I'm trying to write a code for annual interest rate that lets you enter any amount, and it will show you approximately how many years it takes for your money to at least double. The given interest rate is 5% yearly. Thing is, it's not working properly and it's displaying absurdly high numbers, like 200 years or so.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int deposit;
    int counter;

    cout << "Deposit an amount NO LESS than 1000." << endl;
    cin >> deposit;

    for (deposit ;; deposit = 1.05 * deposit) {
        counter = counter+1;

        if (deposit >= 2 * deposit) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Your money will double in "<< counter <<" years." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It is meaningless to ask for the deposit. The result will not change.

Comment: @schorsch312 almost true, if you have 0 money, then depending on how positive your perception is it will either take 0 or infinite amount of time until it doubles ;)

Comment: I will talk to my bank, if they agree on your remark.

Comment: Since this looks like an exercise, do you know if you're allowed to use logarithms? That's the best solution, but if you're just supposed to be practicing loops, it's not really appropriate.

Comment: @Useless nope, just doing this by myself, although our current lesson is about loops, so that's the extent of my knowledge

Comment: @schorsch312, i see, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a loop, you could calculate the time taken to double the money directly.

The amount of money is not interesting, so you don't need to store the amount of money. It's only the rate of return that's interesting.

You can calculate it directly as `log(2) / log(r)` where `r` is the rate of return. For example `log(2) / log(1.05)` gives you the exact time to double an initial amount of money with a 5% return.

Include the standard `<cmath>` header to get `std::log()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  double yearsToDouble = std::log(2) / std::log(1.05);
  std::cout << "Your money will double in "<< yearsToDouble << " years." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: C++ doesn't have imports and it doesn't have packages. This is _including the standard header `cmath`_.

Comment: Just checking: is this correct for _compound_ interest?

Comment: Good idea to drop the unnecessary input though.

Comment: You probalby want to ceil the result, to get the same result as OP. `std::ceil(log(2) / log(1.05))`

Comment: Yep, compound interest is rate-of-return raised to the power of the number of compounding periods. That's assuming _5% yearly_ means 5% compounded annually, anyway (in which case rounding up is also correct, because you need to wait for the complete year to get your interest). If it's really supposed to be monthly compounding with an annualized equivalent rate of 5%, we need to do some more work.

Comment: my current knowledge only extends to loops and if-else statements, since I'm a beginner programmer. how would I implement this logarithm to my code?

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to store the initial deposit so that it can be compared to the cumulative amount with interest.

```
for (float initdeposit = deposit;; deposit = 1.05 * deposit)
{
    counter = counter+1;

    if (deposit >= 2 * initdeposit)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Your money will double in "<< counter <<" years." << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

> a.exe

```
Deposit an amount NO LESS than 1000.
1000

Your money will double in 16 years.
```

Note: No matter what the amount is, the time taken to double will be the same always. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (deposit >= 2 * deposit) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Your money will double in "<< counter <<" years." << endl;
        break;
    }
```

In the above `if` statement you are expecting `deposit` to be greater than or equal to  `2 times of deposit`. Which can only be true in case if the value of `deposit` is zero or less than zero.

I will suggest you to use a `temp` variable to keep the input value of `deposit` and proceed.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, which are largely correct in pointing out that `deposit > 2*deposit` can never be true (you need a second variable to record the initial value!), the only reason your loop ends at all is because `deposit` gets *so large* that `2*deposit` "wraps around" due to overflow.

This appears to make `2*deposit` bigger than `deposit` (logically impossible — you need to fix this comparison!) although strictly speaking the results are undefined.

Apparently this happens to you after 200 or so iterations.

As for suggestions to switch to a floating-point type like `double`, this is tempting, and may be sufficient in this simple case, but as a general rule you should avoid floating-point when you don't need it as it introduces complexities and inaccuracies for very little gain.

I would recommend counting in integer pennies, or tenths of pennies, instead. You can achieve it by multiplying the input by 100 or 1000. The resulting incremental multiplication by 1.05 will have a rounding factor, then, but this is what the banks will be doing too!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if (deposit >= 2 * deposit) {
```

Will not evaluate to `true` (unless `deposit` is negative or barring someedge case). You probably wanted to compare it to an initial value. So after this:

```
cin >> deposit;
```

I would put

```
double initialDeposit = deposit;
```

And then change the other line to

```
if (deposit >= 2 * initialDeposit) {
```

Comment: You're right, I initially thought that might be the problem related to small values. I removed it.